# Justifying the last line of each page?

Tags: margins

Writing up a paper, I noticed that the last line in each page is not always at the same level (sometimes a bit lower/higher than the one on the previous page).

Is there any command to make sure that the last line in each page is always at the same level?

Comment: The directive `\flushbottom`, but that is the default in standard classes.

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes: Yes. Thanks for pointing the typo. (Just in time to fix it!)

Comment: @Bernard Default only for `twoside`d documents.

Comment: @Bernard it isn't the default in article class and report class  unless two column/two side options are used

Comment: @David Carlisle: Didn't know that (I always use `twoside`). Thanks for the  information.

Comment: Does something like `\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}` or `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,div=calc]{scrartcl}` not help?

Comment: Could you provide more information on the class you're using to write your paper? What happens when you issue `\raggedbottom` in your preamble?